# How do I change the color scheme for Visual Studio Code without changing the theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want Visual Studio Code to use my .tmTheme file. The only instructions I can find for directly changing the color scheme involves creating a custom *theme*. I don't want to create an entirely new *theme*, I only want to change the color *scheme*.

How do I change only the color *scheme*?